# How do I manage select options on a multi page webform?

Tags: 7, webforms

With a multi-page webform.

- Page 1: choose country
- Page 2: choose industry
- Page 3: choose from a list of people that support the country and industry.

#validate handler added

```
$form['#validate'][] = '_cbifasttrackcert_webform_validate_sector_country';
```

Adding the items to the list

```
$verifier_options = $verifierHandler->formatVerifierOptions($verifiers);
$form['#node']->webform['components'][$choose_verifiers_cid]['extra']['items'] = 
$verifier_options;
$form_state['webform']['component_tree']['children'][$choose_verifiers_cid]['extra']['items'] = $verifier_options;
```

Which is fine throughout the form, the values don't get submitted as there is a check that values are in the node list.

The challenge is to email a response based on the values, as only *$submission* is available.

When submitting a webform, node_load is used to load a clean version of the options in *select.inc*. These options are used to check whether any valid options have been submitted, with options not in the list being discarded.

*web/sites/all/modules/contrib/webform/components/select.inc* has _webform_select_options() with options to provide a callback or filter based on a token.

I'm not sure how to access form_state using either of these options? Similarly hook node_load does have form_state to allow the options to be discovered?

How to filter a select list based on a token? How to load the form data in a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret is to load all the possible responses in hook_node_load. They are a valid choice, even if submitted. I made it an associative array so that the indexes don't change.

```
function module_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  $choose_verifier_no_verifier_cid = webform_get_cid($webform_node, MyModuleHelper::CHOOSE_VERIFIER_NO_VERIFIER_WEBFORM_KEY)[0];

  $verifier_options = MyModuleHelper::chooseAllVerifiers();
  $webform_node->webform['components'][$choose_verifiers_cid]['extra']['items'] = $verifier_options;
  $webform_node->webform['components'][$choose_verifier_no_verifier_cid]['extra']['items'] = $verifier_options;
```